Typo: blog post date is listed as "October 31, 2025" (a year in the future)
Just reporting a typo on this blog post:



It's also in the URL:

https://stackoverflow.blog/2025/10/31/a-brief-summary-of-language-model-finetuning/



Well it's not ordinary typo in the sense of wrong text/word, it's just a wrong date being picked when creating the blog post. But not sure if/how to edit, so leaving it be.

This got tagged as completed today. Posting this comment so you're notified.

To the close voter(s): Please don't vote to close completed reports as "No longer reproducible". See the answers on Should we close bug reports that are [status-completed]? and Can we replace the "no longer reproducible" close reason with a [status-obsolete] tag?
